# How do I add task bar buttons to my applications?

Tags: java, windows-7

In Windows 7, the Skype application will have buttons when you hover on the taskbar icon that change the user's status:

[image: skype taskbar icons]

See the four status buttons below the standard preview.

How can I add similar buttons to my application?

Comment: You'll either need to write your own native code and integrate it, or hope you can find one of which someone else has written